# Date String Formatting In Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, date

I am currently studying Python String formatting. I have stucked on a problem

I have a string

```
s = "25Aug20"
```

I want to get the date month and year separately

```
sp_list = ['25', 'Aug', '20']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings):

```
sp_list = [s[:2], s[2:5], s[5:]]
```

If you want to get an actual `datetime` object, use [`.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
from datetime import datetime

s = "25Aug20"
print(datetime.strptime(s, "%d%b%y"))
```

this will print

```
2020-08-25 00:00:00
```

Comment: Can you help me to convert it to 25-08-2020 ?

Comment: If you want to get a formatted string (i.e. `"25-08-2020"`) use `mydatetime.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use slicing, as already mentioned in another answer, but I will add that if there is any possibility that you might also need to process strings that use only a single character when dealing with single-digit dates, e.g. `'5Aug20'` (instead of `'05Aug20'` or `' 5Aug20'`), then I suggest slicing relative to the **end** of the string to allow tolerance for this:

```
sp_list = [s[:-5], s[-5:-2], s[-2:]]
```

This should always work, provided only that the number of characters used for the year is always 2, and the number of characters used for the month is always 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Regex

**Ex:**

```
import re

s="25Aug20"
print(re.match(r"(\d+)([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)", s).groups())
# -->('25', 'Aug', '20')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this without using `datetime` and `slicing`

```
s = "25Aug20"

month = ''.join(char for char in s if char.isalpha())
res = s.replace(month, f' {month} ').split()
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
['25', 'Aug', '20']
```